# How can I access an Array List's elements inside an ActionListener from another ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I have two Action Listener inner-classes inside one main class. Each one corresponds to its own button. One of the Action Listeners is coded to generate an Array List. The other simply writes that Array List to a Text Field.

My question is how can I refer to/access that data from the other Action Listener? The code below compiles but when I check the contents of the Array List from the second Action Listener, it is empty ([]).

I'm guessing this has something to do with the Array List re-instantiating when the other Action Listener's actionPerformed method is called. How can I work around this? (The code here is just the 2 Action Listeners).

---

```
// Create a Button Listener Inner Class for Input Route Button.
class InputRouteButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

    List<String> routeStopList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        String city1 = (String) cityCombo1.getSelectedItem();
        String city2 = (String) cityCombo2.getSelectedItem();

        if (city1.equals(city2)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid route chosen. Please choose two different cities.");
        } else {
            routeStopList.add(city1); //Add city1 to start of array.
            int dialogResult;

            do {
                String routeStop = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a stop between the 2 cities:");
                routeStopList.add(routeStop);
                dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Add another stop?");
            } while (dialogResult.equals(JOptionPane.YES_OPTION));

            routeStopList.add(city2); //Add city2 to end of array.
            System.out.println(routeStopList); //Just checking ArrayList contents
        }
    }
}

// Create a Button Listener Inner Class for Route Button.
class RouteButtonHandler extends InputRouteButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        String city1 = (String) cityCombo1.getSelectedItem();
        String city2 = (String) cityCombo2.getSelectedItem();

        System.out.println(routeStopList); //Just checking ArrayList contents

        if (city1.equals(city2)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid route chosen. Please choose two different cities.");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < routeStopList.size(); i++) {
                String addedRoute = routeStopList.get(i);
                adminPanelTextArea.append(addedRoute + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, your problem is due to your creating two ArrayLists, lists that have absolulely no relationship with each other, other than holding the same type of objects and having the same names. A solution is to create one Model class that is shared by both ActionListener classes, and in this model class, have your ArrayList. Then give your ArrayList classes a `setModel(Model model)` method or constructor, and pass in a reference to the single Model object into both ActionListeners.

---

One other consideration is to use a single Control class to handle your listener type code, and then have your Control class hold a Model field.

---

As an aside, this is dangerous code:

```
if (city1 == city2) {
```

Don't compare Strings using `==`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *objects* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

---

For example, say you have two buttons that want to manipulate a JList, one wanting to add text, the other wanting to clear it, then you could pass the JList's model into both button handlers. An example program could look like:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ShareList extends JPanel {
   private static final String PROTOTYPE_CELL_VALUE = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
   private static final int VISIBLE_ROW_COUNT = 10;
   private JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
   private DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
   private JList<String> myList = new JList<>(listModel);

   public ShareList() {
      myList.setPrototypeCellValue(PROTOTYPE_CELL_VALUE);
      myList.setVisibleRowCount(VISIBLE_ROW_COUNT);
      myList.setFocusable(false);

      JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
      AddHandler addHandler = new AddHandler(listModel, this);
      textField.addActionListener(addHandler);
      buttonPanel.add(new JButton(addHandler));
      buttonPanel.add(new JButton(new ClearHandler(listModel)));

      JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      rightPanel.add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      rightPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
      add(new JScrollPane(myList));
      add(rightPanel);
   }

   public String getText() {
      textField.selectAll();
      return textField.getText();
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("ShareList");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new ShareList());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class AddHandler extends AbstractAction {
   private DefaultListModel<String> listModel;
   private ShareList shareList;

   public AddHandler(DefaultListModel<String> listModel, ShareList shareList) {
      super("Add");
      putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_A);
      this.listModel = listModel;
      this.shareList = shareList;
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      String text = shareList.getText();
      listModel.addElement(text);
   };
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ClearHandler extends AbstractAction {
   private DefaultListModel<String> listModel;

   public ClearHandler(DefaultListModel<String> listModel) {
      super("Clear");
      putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_C);
      this.listModel = listModel;
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      listModel.clear();
   };
}
```

Comment: So I will have to create a Model Class that is extended by both Action Listeners and within it have: 

`List<String> routeStopList = new ArrayList<String>();`.

Then I would need a method/constructor inside that Model Class through which Strings from the Action Listeners would be appended to the Array List.

Comment: @gsymeoni: no, Model never **implements** ActionListener. That's the control's job. Please read up on MVC (model-view-control) design pattern for the details.

Comment: @gsymeoni: again the model will hold your ArrayList, and your control or if you want your two ActionListener-implementing classes will hold a reference to the one same model. This way changes to the model in one class will be reflected in the other class.

Comment: @gsymeoni: alternatively, your ArrayList could be your model in this simple program, and in this situation all you have to do is pass a reference to the same array list to each ActionListener. Again, pass it in via either a constructor parameter or a setter method.